# Why does MySQL demand arguments in a specific order?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I wrestled with these two for awhile:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '...' INTO TABLE ... 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '!' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

That works great. What does *not* work, is this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '...' INTO TABLE ... 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '!';
```

Why not? Isn't the meaning identical? What is the rationale behind this? Are there examples where changing the order of arguments such as these changes the result?

Comment: It's up MySQL to define syntax rules.

Comment: Certainly, I'm asking what the rationale is behind this.

Comment: Probably for the same reason the query order is defined.  `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...` works, but `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... WHERE` does not.  Sure, reading it they mean the same thing.  But the compiler isn't expecting it in that order.   It's just how the language syntax was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's a) the way the query engine works, and b) because the guy who wrote it didn't want to go through the hassle of coding it to allow for variable order of optional clauses with an SQL parser because that doesn't really add much value.

Ultimately, it's the same reason `ls file.txt -a` and `file.txt -a ls` aren't the same shell commands, or the reason you have to use `x = 6 * (9 + 2)` instead of `x = 6 9 2 + *` in C.  The answer is because there's a syntax and it has rules.

Comment: Some things have no reason to be arbitrarily reordered. This is one of those things. +1.